# Failed To Fetch Error with Django Application

Tags: javascript, django, asynchronous, fetch

Working on a Django app and running in to a `failed to fetch` error intermittently from my JS code.

You can see the network responses below - where the error is intermittent from the server (currently on localhost:8000)
[image]

My django server logs are showing nothing - so 'connection refused' and 'empty response' are confusing.

On the JS side I am using

```
fetch(data.getAttribute('action'), {
            method: data.getAttribute('method'),
            body: new FormData(data),
            headers:{ "X-CSRFToken": csrf_token, "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"},
          }).then(res=>res.json())
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                document.getElementById('create-submit-button').style.border = "2px solid #ebebeb" 

              if(data.status == 'success'){
                //happy path will be to add photos on good response
                console.log('happy path')
              } else {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'there was an issue with your request',
                    text: data.message,
                  })
              } 
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('Error: ', error))
        }
```

My django view is as follows:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def create(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest' and request.user.is_authenticated:
            print(request.POST)
            form = SpinForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = request.user
                spin = Spin()
                spin.prompt = form.cleaned_data['prompt']
                spin.user = user
                spin.orientation = form.cleaned_data['orientation']
                # save spin to get many to many relationship
                spin.save()
                spin.themes.add(*form.cleaned_data['themes'])
                # update users total spins
                user.current_spins += 1
                user.save()

                # themes = request.POST.getlist('theme')
                computed_prompt = ''

                if len(spin.themes.all()) > 0:
                    for theme in spin.themes.all():
                        computed_prompt += ' ' + theme.prompt_text

                # save spin again after attaching themes + computed prompt
                spin.computed_prompt = computed_prompt
                spin.final_prompt = spin.prompt + ' ' + computed_prompt
                spin.save()

                try:
                    ThirdPartyApi.spin(request.user, spin)
                except Exception as e:
                    print('%s' % type(e))
                    print(e)
                    return JsonResponse({
                        'status': 'failed',
                        'message': 'stable-d shit'
                    })

                # stable d api shit right here
                return JsonResponse({
                    'status': 'success',
                    'spin': 'win'
                })
            else:
                print(form.errors.as_data())
                return JsonResponse({
                    'status': 'failed',
                    'message': str(form.errors.as_data())
                })
        else:
            return JsonResponse({
                'status': 'failed',
                'message': 'non ajax or user not logged in',
            })

    else:
        spin = SpinForm()
        themes = Theme.objects.all().order_by('created_at')
        context = {
            'form': spin,
            'themes': themes
        }
    return render(request, 'templates/create/create.html', context)
```

I do call a `ThirdPartyApi` which uses GRPC and takes some time to compute (an AI api). That being said I'm really miffed by the intermittent nature of it working/not working. Any tips greatly appreciated to solve the failed to fetch issue.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who hits this issues - i ran into limitations with the django dev server. as soon as i swapped to nginx + gunicorn the problems went away completely. it would be nice if the django dev would spit something out when it blows up. turns out it is also single threaded and i'm doing a bunch of image manipulation that probably has some cleanup so the thread stays locked. use nginx + a w/asgi server!